# Extract sequence header for a given sequence in fasta file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a fasta file(myfasta.fasta) like this:

```
>aat.2.2344.a
ATTGCCGGTTTAATATTA
>aat.2.d2344.acc
ATTGCCGGTTTAATAAA
>aat.2.2bb344.a
ATTGCCGGTTTAATAGGAGAGAATT
>aat.2.2ccc344.a
ATTGCCGGTTTAATAGGGAG
>aat.2.2344.acc
ATTGCCGGTTTAATAAA
```

I also have a text file `my.txt` which contains the sequence that matches the sequence in fasta file above:

```
ATTGCCGGTTTAATAAA
```

Based on this sequence I want to extract all matched IDs for this sequence. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks!

The result I want is:

```
>aat.2.2344.acc
>aat.2.d2344.acc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *grep* and *sed*:

```
grep --no-group-separator -B 1 "ATTGCCGGTTTAATAAA" my.txt | sed -n 1~2p
>aat.2.d2344.acc
>aat.2.2344.acc
```

See answer by [@QuoraFeans](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264492/16560) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

assuming your input data format is consistent with example

```
$ awk -v v='ATTGCCGGTTTAATAAA' '/>/{id=$0} $1==v{print id}' file

>aat.2.d2344.acc
>aat.2.2344.acc
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in bioawk, it is an adapted version of awk which is tuned to process fasta files

```
bioawk -c fastx -v str="ATTGCCGGTTTAATAAA" '($seq == str) { print ">"$name }' file.fasta
```

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|.*|/^&$/{x;p}|' keyFile | sed -n -e 'h;n' -f - fastaFile
```

Create a sed script from the key file and run it against the fasta file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python!
Create a file called extract_fasta.py. Insert this in the file:

```
lines = open("myfasta.fasta").readlines()

for line in lines:
    if line[0] == '>':
        print(line[1:])
```

Then, open the terminal and run "python extract_fasta.py".